# Mathmistry , Deriving bond angles.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, lagrange-multiplier

Consider a sphere with n points, and the objective is to find their placement in a way that maximizes the distance between them. Initially, I attempted to solve the problem for 2 points by maximizing the expression (x1-x2)^2 + (y1-y2)^2 with the constraint x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = r^2, and it yielded the correct result. However, when I extended the approach to 3 points, trying to maximize the area enclosed by these points, it did not produce the desired outcome. I am uncertain about what went wrong, and I am seeking guidance on how to approach the problem for n points.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2088788/placing-n-points-on-a-sphere, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/31619/well-separated-points-on-sphere, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4060934/create-n-points-that-are-spaced-as-far-as-possible-within-a-d-dimensional-sphere